# parsing data in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have following string in Jquery

```
[{
  "Key": ["Month", "Dealer Lastname", "Gurpreetttttt Alowaliaaaaaaaaa", "Intekhab Khan", "Intekhab Khan", "Test Test"]
}, {
  "Key": ["Jan", 600, 500, 0, 300, 100]
}]
```

I want to parse this string.When ever i try to alert the data it give me object object

```
var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
$.each(resp, function (key, val) {
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: You can't alert an object, you should be using the console for this (F12), and you would have figured it out a lot easier.

Comment: I agree. Your keys are simple strings, but the value is actually an array. If you don't want to use the console, you could "alert(value.join())" which would show you the comma separated values in that array.

Comment: Since noone else is doing it, here's a quick [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/HATqE/2/) that shows how to get all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you alert an object, you will get the string representation of the object, which by default is the type name of the object.

You can alert the `Key` property of the object instead, to see the content:

```
$.each(resp, function(key, val) {
  alert(val.Key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have key named `Key` in json array so:

```
 $.each(resp, function (key, val) {
    alert(val['Key']);
 });
```